# Hide cursor (and marks) in all windows while using avy or ace-window

Tags: avy, ace-window

I find occasionally hard to read the labels from `avy` or `ace-window` when they overlap with the cursor (I have `cursor-on-non-selected-window` set to `t`).  Same issue with `ace-window` (even more relevant since many times the cursor is sitting at pos 0).  Is there a proper way to hide cursors (and `visible-mark`s) temporarily while using `avy` or `ace-window`?

A possibility would be to override the faces while using the commands, but I wonder if there is a more proper approach

Comment: I don't use either library, but the *buffer-local* variable you may be interested in setting to `nil` on a temporary basis is `cursor-type`.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works under the assumption the cursor type is same everywhere. It uses `setq-default` for buffer-local variables `cursor-in-non-selected-windows` and `cursor-in-non-selected-windows`.

```
;; When the inactive cursor is on one of the avy targets,
;; the overlay and cursor colors mix and the avy sequence gets hard to read.
;; Let's fix this by hiding cursor everywhere.
(defun avy-jump-advice--hide-cursor-temporarily (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((ct  cursor-type)
        (ctn cursor-in-non-selected-windows))
    (setq-default cursor-in-non-selected-windows nil)
    (setq-default cursor-type nil)
    (apply orig-func args)
    (setq-default cursor-type ct)
    (setq-default cursor-in-non-selected-windows ctn)))
(advice-add 'avy-jump :around #'avy-jump-advice--hide-cursor-temporarily)
```